# Show this distance function is not a metric

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation

This is problem 3B, pg.79

Let $\mathfrak{I}([0,1])$ denote the collection of all functions from $[0,1]$ into R such that$\int_0^1|f(x)| dx$ exists.

For $f \in \mathfrak{I}([0,1])$ where
$d(f,g)=\int_0^1 |f(x)-g(x)| dx$

(We are given the the hint :if $f(x)=1$ for
$0<x\leq 1$ and $f(0)=2$ does $d(f,g)$ exist?)

Using half the hint
$d(f,g)=d(1,g)=\int_0^1|1-g(x)|dx$

Then
$d(1,g)=0$ iff $g(x)=1$

After this, I am stumped, and I have no idea what to do next.
Any help would be appreciated.

*Source: A First Course in Topology: Conover*

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the formulas in your MSE posts.

Comment: I thought l did for the integral and interval notation.

Comment: MathJax is for formatting entire formulas. I've edited your post. I hope you'll agree that it looks much better if you put the $\$$s around complete formulas, not just the individual symbols.

Comment: As to the mathematics: are you using the Riemann integral or the Lebesgue integral? And what is the relevance of the term "indiscrete topology" in the title of your question?

Comment: The given hint is basically asking you to observe that $d(f,0)=\int_0^1 |f(x)| \, dx=0$ but the function is NOT the zero function (as $f(0)=2$). Thus a non-zero function $f$ is also  at a "distance" $0$ from the zero function, which contradicts the definition.

Comment: If the answer that you have accepted is appropriate, then this is nothing to do with the indiscrete topology. Please change your title to something more relevant.

Comment: Well $\mathfrak{J}$ is used Indiscrete topology,so I thought it had something to do with it. They are using it twice and upon rereading it,you’re correct

Comment: @RobArthan: It's always about the $, isn't it? ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a metric because we can find different functions that have distance zero between each other, and a condition we require for $d$ to be a metric is that $$d(f,g)=0\iff f=g.$$ You could take, for example, the function $f$ you described and the constant function $g(x)=1$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Then
$$
\int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|dx=0 
$$
but $f\neq g$.

If, instead, you take the space of equivalence classes of measurable functions that differ only on a measure zero set (called $L^1[0,1]$), then $d$ becomes a metric.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true without the additional assumption that the functions are all measurable.  Let $f(x) =-1~ \forall x \in E, f(x)=-1~ \forall x \in [0, 1] \setminus E$, where $E$ is not measurable.  Let $g(x)$ be the constant function $1$.  Then the "metric" $d$ isn't even defined.

Answer (score 2):

Your "metric" $d$ isn't even defined everywhere without the additional assumption that $\mathfrak I$ is restricted to measurable functions.  Let $f(x) =-1~ \forall x \in E, f(x)=-1~ \forall x \in [0, 1] \setminus E$, where $E$ is not measurable.  Let $g(x)$ be the constant function $1$.  Then the "metric" $d(f, g)$ isn't even defined.

Comment: $\mathfrak I$ is the set of integrable functions, therefore they are measurable.

Comment: @Alan Not so.  The function $f$ defined in my answer fits the definition of $\mathfrak I$, but it's not measurable.

Comment: Apologies. Could you explain this further? the function you defined is constant. If you mean $f(x)=1\forall x\in E$ and $f(x)=-1$ otherwise, then $f$ is not measurable and we cannot even talk about the Lebesgue integral of $f$, as far as i know.

Comment: But we don't need to talk about the Lebesgue integral of $f$.  $\mathfrak I$ is defined in terms of $\vert f \vert$, which *is* measurable even though $f$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in some cases we may turn a distance function into a metric through quotients.  In $L^2[a,b]$, the space of square-integrable functions, i.e., functions $f$ for which  $$\int_a^b f^2d\mu$$, where $\mu$ is a measure , we define ( in $L^2[a,b]$ we usually use the Lebesgue Measure), we define a distance function $$d(f,g):=\int_a^b |f-g|^2d\mu$$
This is not quite a metric, since $d(f,g)=0$ when $f=g$ a.e ( almost everywhere, i.e., equal outside of a set of measure $0$). But, if we _ declare_ that two functions $f,g$ are equal when they're a.e equal, then our distance function becomes a metric , albeit on the class of functions that are a.e equal .

Comment: Any comments on the downvote?